# How to get which dependence cause useCallback / useMemo recalculate?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, memo, usecallback

By using `useMemo` / `useCallback` hook in React, sometimes I find many unexpected render causing by `useMemo` / `useCallback` return value.

As I use `React.memo` to reduce React function component useless render, by `React.memo` second param, I could control over the comparison. **Also, I can get which prop cause current render.** Like after:

```js
const MemoComponent = React.memo((props) => {}, (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  for (const key in prevProps) {
    const prevValue = prevProps[key];
    const nextValue = nextProps[key];

    if (prevValue !== nextValue) {
      return false; // form here I can get which cause render
    }
  }

  return true;
})
```

**May I get which dependence cause `useCallback` / `useMemo` recalculate like before or React devtools?**